# What is an Accolade?

Tags: the-division

I have crafted a yellow 'High end' quality item and the random bonus I got was 'Rewards from Accolades are tripled'.

[image: Pictre of Tactical pads]

So what is an Accolade, and how do I earn one to get triple of whatever the reward might be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to a [gamefaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/718815-tom-clancys-the-division/73417308) thread, Accolades are the orange badges that pop up when you complete certain tasks, like reviving, headshots, multikills,... these usually reward XP, so for a max level reward, this bonus is somewhat lost. However, there is speculation that this also applies to Darkzone XP.

Comment: Urgh, typical! I guess I'll have to craft it again and hope for a better bonus. Not a great start for my first high-end gear piece.

Comment: Additionally there is a perk from the Security Wing called `Combat Veteran` which gives you a 25% boost to accolades.

Comment: Even crazier, @dougajmcdonald, that Perk is from the Barracks, the most expensive upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

who cares about speculation when testing take 30 seconds?

That gear piece, according to my test, doesn't triple dz xp.

With = 175xp

Without = 175xp.

but test yourself! dam bug game, shoved out whilst people wait for BF.

Comment: If you'd like to leave a comment, please use the `add a comment` link beneath the answer.